# Заполнить точками пустое пространство между словами

Tags: html, css

Необходимо реализовать оформление, которое выглядит как оглавление в книге:
часть текста на строке прижата влево, часть - вправо, а расстояние между концом левого и началом правого заполняется точками.
Строк будет несколько.
При этом длина текста с обоих концов заранее неизвестна, может изменяться, и на каждой строке она будет разной.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Необходимо добавить [псевдоэлемент `:after`](https://webref.ru/css/after) для элемента, который формирует строку. Контентом для этого псевдоэлемента будет большое число точек, которыми надо заполнить строку (лучше брать с небольшим запасом). Добавление свойства `overflow: hidden` позволит обрезать "лишние" точки, когда она дойдут до начальной границы правого текста. Свойства `display: block` и `white-space: nowrap` отключат перенос строки при переполнении её контентом, т.к. точки в псевдоэлементе определённо сделают строку длинее, чем ширина контейнера.
Для красоты можно добавлять отступы для текста перед точками и после них, а также отступ слева в начале строки, чтобы сформировать каскадную вложенность пунктов - заполнение пустой строки точками нарушено не будет.

```css
.book {
  width: 250px;
}
p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
p:after {  content:'..................................................';
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p span:first-of-type {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
p span:last-of-type {
  float:right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

p:last-of-type{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <h1>Оглавление</h1>
  <p><span>Предисловие</span><span></span></p>
  <p><span>1. Завязка</span><span>стр. 1</span></p>
  <p><span>2. Кульминация</span><span>стр. 10</span></p>
  <p><span>3. Развязка</span><span>стр. 100</span></p>
  <p><span>Послесловие</span><span></span></p>
  <p><span>Об авторе</span><span></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Я бы вот так сделал.

```css
ul li,
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0 .4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <h1>Оглавление</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Предисловие</li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <div>Завязка</div>
          <div></div>
          <div>стр. 1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Кульминация</div>
          <div></div>
          <div>стр. 10</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Развязка</div>
          <div></div>
          <div>стр. 100</div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Послесловие</li>
    <li>Об авторе</li>
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению, IE всё ещё не дружит с [`display: flex`](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), да и мобильных на старом андроиде ещё достаточно

Answer (score 1):

---

```css
.list li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.list a {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.list a:hover{
  color: #ff0000;
}
.list a span+span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
.wr-line-dotted {
  width: 100%;
}
.line-dotted {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
.list li ul{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-section list">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Раздел I</span>
        <span class="wr-line-dotted">
          <span class="line-dotted"></span>
        </span>
        <span>cтр. 15</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Раздел II</span>
        <span class="wr-line-dotted">
          <span class="line-dotted"></span>
        </span>
        <span>cтр. 100</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Раздел III</span>
        <span class="wr-line-dotted">
          <span class="line-dotted"></span>
        </span>
        <span>cтр. 256</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-paragraph list">
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Параграф 1</span>
            <span class="wr-line-dotted">
              <span class="line-dotted"></span>
            </span>
            <span>cтр. 257</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Параграф 2</span>
            <span class="wr-line-dotted">
              <span class="line-dotted"></span>
            </span>
            <span>cтр. 384</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```