# Как правильно сверстать характеристики товара?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как правильно сверстать характеристики такого плана?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно интересно, делать таблично или блочно? И вопрос с точками... как их растягивать? border-bottom?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548666/196573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Семантически подобные списки ближе к [definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp) (теги `dl`, `dt`, `dd`). Только пара "термин-определение" идет в одну строку, и после термина идет отточие.

Само отточие здорово передавать именно точками, текстом, а не `border-bottom: dotted`.

Рабочий пример:

```css
dl {
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dt-dotted {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.dt-dotted > span {
  position: relative;
}
    
.dt-dotted > span:after {
  color: #000;
  content: '..............................................................';
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.dl-inline > dt {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
  
.dl-inline > dd {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-inline">
  <dt class="dt-dotted">
    <span>Вес</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>36 шт</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="dl-inline">
  <dt class="dt-dotted">
    <span>Количество на поддоне</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>48 шт</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="dl-inline">
  <dt class="dt-dotted">
    <span>Прочность на сжатие</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>200-400 кгс/см</dd>
</dl>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/os2d4gwa/)

Answer (score 7):

Еще вариант:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.item__label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  
}

.item__label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  right: -9999px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #888;
}

.left {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item__cor {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="left">
      <span class="item__label">Вес</span>
    </div>
    <span class="item__cor">36 шт</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="left">
      <span class="item__label">Количество на поддоне</span>
    </div>
    <span class="item__cor">48 шт</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="left">
      <span class="item__label">Прочность</span>
    </div>    
    <span class="item__cor">200 - 400 кг/см</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

То же с таблицей:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.cur {
  width: 30%;
}

.name {  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.name span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.name span:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  right: -9999px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"><span>Вес</span></td>
      <td class="cur">36 шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"><span>Количество на поддоне</span></td>
      <td class="cur">48 шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"><span>Прочность</span></td>
      <td class="cur">200 - 400 кг/см</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```