# Как заполнить пустое расстояние между текстом точками?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Пример желаемого]

В случае js ищу только нативное решение

Comment: Прям любые и бредовые? 3 дива в ряд, крайним float-left\right; и текст соответственно левый\правый. центральному заполнение в 100% по ширине и бэкграунд на рипите, а на картинке точка

Comment: Про любые написал, чтобы тело вопроса заполнить

Comment: Ну вот какие просили - те и предложил =) На техническом ресурсе заполнять текст водой - так себе идея.

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему мой вопрос хейтят, а вопрос по типу "http и https - это одно и тоже или нет?" получает много плюсов?

Comment: Вот поэтому хэйтят, это первое что находится по первой же ссылке из поисковика Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Заполнить точками пустое пространство между словами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548666/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Хэйтят по той причине, что я не понимаю?) Я облазил кучу тем на cyberforum'е и не нашел нужного, там либо 100 с лишним строчек кода, либо jquery и т.п. .Вариант на stack'е это не совсем то, что мне было нужно

Comment: Видимо вы нас ошибочно за телепатов приняли, и мы должны были догадаться что вам надо без jQuery без 100 строчек кода, и прочих условий которые вы уже озвучили или только думаете над ними =)

Comment: @Nikita В моем представлении stackoverflow месте где можно найти ответ на деликатный точечный вопрос программирования, например: "почему a = b, a = null, b != null". То есть предполагается что вы самостоятельно максимально продвинулись в решении своей задачи, но уперлись в какую то специфику языка и без помощи справиться не можете. И вопрос должен быть поставлен в развернутом виде, описывающим в чем, собственно, сложность. Но не так, что бы - "вот макет, нужно запилить на джиесе".

Comment: @VladimirMorulus, я держу такое же мнение про stackoverflow, но когда вопрос чуть менее базовый, то он вообще не получает никакого отклика

Comment: @Sevastopol', хорошо так думать, но, к примеру, в данной теме https://cutt.ly/yrTSNJw я дал понять, что я хочу, как я попытался это сделать и предоставил код

Comment: @Sevastopol', вы же понимаете, что я речь про игнорирование ввел о других вопросах, вы отвечаете, что будут соблюдены некоторые правила, никто не будет игнорить, я и показал пример, где вопрос корректкен, но нет активности

Comment: @Sevastopol', там не может быть какой-либо еще доп информации или упущенных деталей. Есть обьект из дб, и нужно удалить свойство, какие могут быть тут детали?

Answer (score 2):

А лучше действительно для начала поискать, а потом уже и спрашивать. Без обид)

Много есть разных вариантов. Вот самый простой:

```css
ul.dots li {
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.dots li span:first-child {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

ul.dots li span+span {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

ul.dots li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dots">
  <li><span>Один</span><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>Два</span><span>22</span></li>
  <li><span>Три</span><span>333</span></li>
  <li><span>Десять</span><span>000000000000</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Чем ваше решение отличается от приведенного в комментарии?

Comment: Наверное потому что вопрос дубликат, и приведена ссылка на вопрос, где есть такой же ответ =) зачем плодить дубликаты?